# What to do, Learn while Developing the app or Learn first and then develop the app

Tags: php, iphone, android

I am planning to develop a web and mobile application. Have a look on this [Question on OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/19073/i-have-a-great-idea-for-a-startup-a-web-app-business-how-and-where-to-start)

I have some PHP & MySql knowledge, however I didn't do any major projects so far.

My skills on a scale of 5

- PHP&MySql 3/5,
- Javascript 3/5
- CSS 3/5
- Android 1.5/5
- IPhone    0/5
- web development (2/5)
- web    design(2/5)
- Software Development &    management
  (1.5/5)
- My app, as said in one of the answers
  in the question, is not much complex
  as Mint. If the complexity of Mint is
  rated 8. My app would be 5/8

I have lot of interest in programming. Only thing bothering and bogging me is the time to make the app live. I don't understand how to estimate the time as I am not so experienced.

Should I start developing the app and learn all the concepts on the way?

or

should I wait learn programming completely first and then develop the app.?

Edit: A small Edit based on below answers. How should I test myself to know whether I have the minimum web development knowledge to start developing the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ckuetbach said you cannot really "learn programming completely" first. Because of the distinction practical/theoretical you must really learn-by-doing.

Here is what I would do:

1). Clearly define the apps functionality (first version functionality that is).

2). Try to understand what you can reuse in both the browser and the mobile applications (so as not to program the same thing twice). Example would be to keep the business logic on the server and access it via REST or something from the mobile app instead of programming it in there as well (if you want to make applications for both iPhone and Android phones you would have to develop the business logic once in ObjectiveC and once in Java). Obvious disadvantage is that the apps cannot think unless the phones are online (but I cannot judge that since I don't know exactly what you are doing).

3). Start coding (and learn while doing so, your best friend here is google, because it allows you to learn from how others who have done it before). Work in modules (and after the completion of a module jump to point 4).

4). Test (and test and test and test).

5). Iterate points 3 + 4 until you are satisfied for a first version (I say this because it is important do define the functionality you want in a first version; there is a clear relation between the amount of functionality and the amount of time it will take you to actually release the app).

6). Finally release the first version (and then start again from point 1, building on v1 to make v2).

** And like codie said: using an MVC framework is good for learning because it forces you (mostly) to program intelligently...plus the framework code is probably going to be better than what you would be able to do (or I for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

Learn while developing the first version of the app, then throw it all away (unless of course, you actually made it rather maintainable) and then remake/update it with what you've learned.

And keep asking here, not just if you run into errors, but also if you're not sure what you're doing is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend getting hold of an MVC framework and figure out how to create applications with it. Without taking time out to "study" web application development, complying with the development pattern enforced by a framework is the best best to writing maintainable web applications. I have twice (in two different companies) come across projects that started as small hacks, didn't follow much structural organisation of code and ended up being extremely messy to enhance later on.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on wether you're gonna develop the project alone, or eventually let other people join you in your development. Having some experiences in working with beginner-programmers, I'd say the biggest problem is the way they structure (or don't structure) the application and code they produce, often making it very difficult to get an understanding of the structure and layout.

If you're in this on your own though, I'd say just go for it, start programming and learn on the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to "programming completely" first. So you have to start to code your app learn, refactor your code, learn again, code, lear and refactor....

Don't be afraid to start coding while you are still learning.

Don't stop learning, if you already started to code.

Answer (score 0):

You have offered yourself the option of hiring professionals. That seems the most logical thing to do. Unless of course, you don't have the resources for it. The problem is that if you struggle on your own, chances are that eventually you will have a unsound code base, that cannot be maintained by anybody but you.